# how to add onclick event on @Html.RadioButtonFor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-5.0

My radio button basically has a model value.

How can I add an click-eventhandler on `@Html.RadioButtonFor` ?

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(
  model => model.AnswerResponse, 
  true, 
  new { id = "Yes"}, 
  new { onclick = "alert('hi')" 
})
```

`@Html.RadioButtonFor` does not contain four arguments.

Comment: What library/framework is this?

Comment: Asp.net core 5.0

Comment: I think it would help if you use appropiate tags on your question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the onClick handler using the `onclick` html attribute

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(
  model => model.AnswerResponse, 
  true, 
  new { @tabIndex = 1, @id = "Yes", @onclick="alert('hi')" }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your button is the only one and has a class(or an id by switch . to #), you can do :

```
const buttonThatIWantToCall = document.querySelector('.MyElementClass')
```

This calls the element in a variable. Then, you can verify whenever the element in this variable is called with :

```
buttonThatIWantToCall.addEventListener('click', Function);
```

then, just do whatever you want to do in the function.

Comment: The OP seems to be using some library/framework. There might be a better way to attach a click callback to the button.